# How VIX ETF Rolls to follow the SP 500 VIX Index

Tags: volatility, index, vix, etf

I was reading the Methodology that S&P uses in order to construct VIX index [VIX S&P Methodology](https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/documents/methodologies/methodology-sp-vix-futures-indices.pdf) If I understood it right, the VIX Short-Term Futures Index works as follows:

[image]

Notice that both weights in the numerator an denominator are from the day (t-1) and are defined as:

[image]

and

[image]

So they have a daily rolling that is a fraction of the Contract Roll period. At the start of the period dr/dr = 1/(Days Between Periods) and (dt - dr)/dt = (Days Between Periods - 1)/(Days Between Periods)

So far so good.

What I don't understand is how an ETF for example iPath® Series B S&P 500® VIX Short-Term Futures™ ETN (VXX) Implements this and manages the excess or the lack of nominal to perform the roll.

Let me put an example to explain it:

October 12, 2022:

VIX 1º Line: 32.174

VIX 2º Line: 31.778

When doing the roll, 1/(Days Between Periods) ¿contracts? are sold for the 1º Line futures and 1/(Days Between Periods) ¿contracts? are bought for the 2º Line futures, if so, and supposing that 1/(Days Between Periods) = 1, they will receive 32.174 for the sell of the 1º Line contract and they will buy the second line at 31.778 having an excess of liquidity 0.396 USD/contract. How does the ETF manage the Liquidity excess?

(If the Forward curve is in Contango, there will be the opposite problem, they will not have enough liquidity to buy the second-line futures)

I expose another problem, that is maybe related, The VIX index have reversion towards the mean (bewteen 10-40) but looking at SP 500 VIX Mid Term Futures TRI, the historical chart is negative exponential ( with a starting value in 2008 at 222k and an actual value of 19k):

[image: SP 500 VIX Mid Term Futures TRI Index Chart (SPVIXMTR)]

How this is explained? This cannot be due to transaction cost as it is not the ETF is the Index

Comment: Please review how futures work. You do not receive 32.174 in cash for closing the oct future and you do not need to put up cash in the amount of 31.778 to enter into the Nov future. There is no cash generated or absorbed by a futures roll.

Comment: Good Point!, let me see if I understand it right, As all the assets in the ETF are Futures, as the ETF ISSUER only have to cover the Initial/Variation Margin, they could invest the rest with T-Bills and that's how the VIX Total Return can be created?

And on the other hand, the negative/positive P&L for the Roll Out position is directly reflected in the ETF price and assumed by the Investor when selling the position.

What happens if the value of the VIX changes so much that the liquidity provided by investors to the ETF cannot cover the margin call costs?

Thank You So Much!

Comment: Yes, "all they have to do" is make sure the margin requirement is covered. But if god forbid they are unable to, it could be a total disaster. I remember in Feb 2018 a VIX ETF went out of business because of a vix spike.